# Berkovich Integration on algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, analytic-geometry, projective-varieties, berkovich-geometry

Berkovich developed a theory of integrating one-forms on his analytic spaces in his book "Integration of One-forms on $P$-adic analytic spaces". As this book is difficult to digest for me, I am wondering how this theory breaks down, if one just considers analytifications of smooth projective curves. More specifically, I am wondering if his theory can be used to translate some of the result over $\mathbb C$ (which I will recall below) to the $p$-adic world.

In the complex world the moduli space $\Omega M_g$ of pairs $(X, \omega)$, where $X$ is a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ and $0 \neq \omega\in H^0(X, \Omega_X)$ is a holomorphic differential on $X$, is a well studied object. The space $\Omega M_g$ is a complex orbifold and the points are called translation surfaces. One first result is that every translation surface can be represented as a finite union of polygons in the complex plane with edge identifications. One gets this equivalence by integrating (using $\omega$) along paths between the zeros of $\omega$.

$\Omega M_g$ comes equipped with a natural stratification: Let $\kappa$ be a partition of $2g-2$ (the number of zeros of $\omega$ counting multiplicity). Then $\mathcal H(\kappa)$ is the subset of $\Omega M_g$ containing the points $(X,\omega)$ such that the order of zeros of $\omega$ corresponds to the partition $\kappa$. This subset $\mathcal H (\kappa)$ is itself a complex orbifold. Roughly speaking, charts are given by integrating the same paths with respect to different differentials.
If you want more details on this topic, I would suggest having a look at a nice overview paper by: [Alex Wright](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ealexmw/StonyBrookSurvey.pdf)

I would like to bring those two results over to the $p$-adic world ($\mathbb C_p$), so let me restate my question:

- Using Berkovich integration on the analytification of a projective smooth curve $X$, is there a nice geometric description of the pair $(X^{an},\omega)$ (where $\omega$ is a global section of the differentials on $X^{an}$)?
- On the strata of $\Omega M_g$ (which exists algebraically) can we find some kind of "coordinates" by integrating using the differentials?

I would appreciate any kind of feedback, whether those results are clearly unobtainable or might very well be possible.

Comment: Just a comment on your first question. Which kind of ``nice geometric description'' do you have in mind? I am not sure what the analogue of a polygon should be in Berkovich geometry and gluing edges can certainly be problematic. Maybe gluing discs along their boundaries? Do you have any examples where you see how things work?

Comment: @JérômePoineau Unfortunately I don't have any examples. One could certainly make something similar as the second definition of translation surface in the paper of Wright: By locally integrating using $\omega$ (as one would do over $\mathbb C$) one can get a $p$-adic manifold, i.e. charts to $\mathbb C_p$. But since $\mathbb C_p$ is totally disconnected this is not really usefull I think...